# How to update parent component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, render, use-effect

so I am trying to update my parent component whenever I scroll to the bottom. When I do scroll to the bottom, I am calling fetchData, which is in the parent component and is a dependency in the useEffect, however, the component does not update, leaving me with data from the first component render.

The first 7 sets of data is fetched successfully, and when I scroll to the bottom, fetchData is called again, however the component does not update, however when I then click save on the parent component, then the next sets of data is successfully loaded and displayed to the screen as it should. I feel I am doing something wrong i'm just clueless as to what it is. Any help would be very much appreciated

This is the parent component:

```
function Following({route, navigation}) {
  const [followingData, setfollowingData] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [lastVisible, setLastVisible] = useState(0);

  const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
    const dataRef = firestore().collection('usernames');

    dataRef
      .doc(route.params.username.toLowerCase())
      .collection('Following')
      .orderBy('followedAt')
      .startAfter(lastVisible)
      .limit(7)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const last = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
        setLastVisible(last.data().followedAt);
        let promises = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          promises.push(
            data.path.get().then((res) => {
              const userData = res.data();
              return {
                profileName: doc.id ? doc.id : null,
                displayName: userData.displayName ? userData.displayName : null,
                followerCount:
                  userData.followers !== undefined ? userData.followers : 0,
                followingCount:
                  userData.following !== undefined ? userData.following : 0,
                imageUrl: userData.imageUrl ? userData.imageUrl : null,
              };
            }),
          );
        });
        Promise.all(promises).then((res) => {
          setfollowingData(res);
        });
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const dataRef = firestore().collection('usernames');

    const cleanup = dataRef
      .doc(route.params.username.toLowerCase())
      .collection('Following')
      .onSnapshot(fetchData);

    return cleanup;
  }, [route.params.username, fetchData]);

  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black" />
      ) : (
        <>
          <FolloweringScreens
            data={followingData}
            screen={'Following'}
            username={route.params.username}
            navigation={navigation}
            fetchData={fetchData}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Following;
```

And the child component is:

```
function FolloweringScreens({
  data,
  screen,
  username,
  navigation,
  fetchData
}) {

  return (
    <>
      <FlatList
        scrollEnabled={true}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0}
        onEndReached={fetchData}
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(i, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => {
          return (
            <>
                (`All my data being used here`)
           </>
      );
    }}
  />
</>
```

);
}

export default FolloweringScreens;

Comment: why are you using `useCallback` on the `fetchData` function?

Comment: Should I not use this? I was told it would optimize performance

Comment: `useCallback` will memoize the last returned value and will only re-run it in case the dependencies changed, and you are passing an empty array as a dependency. That means that this function will not be "re-run" and the first returned value will be memoized. It is used to performance optimization but on places where a function is called multiple times in a period where the dependencies might not change. In your case, looks like it will be called only when you scroll all the way down and the internal values used are different, so it's not helpful.

Comment: maybe google a bit on how it works, check docs and tutorials like https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback :)

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you for the explanation, I will remove useCallback and fetch the data ffrom the useEffect. I would like to ask however, what if i added a dependency to the useCallback, would it re-run so i could get a different returned value?

Comment: You should still keep the `fetchData` function as is, just remove the `useCallback` wrapper. If you add the dependencies, yes, it will re-run and get different values when one of the dependencies change.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I have direction now on what to do. Appreciate the help sir